# Apex trigger Bulkification problem

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

Custom Objects:
Associate__c
Product__c
Order__c
Associate__c(Lookup of Associate)

Order_Entry__c
Order__c (Lookup of Order__c)
Product__c (Lookup of Product__c)
Quantity__c (Number 5,0)

Inventory__c
Status__c (Picklist => 'Assigned', 'Ordered', 'Sold')
Associate__c (Lookup of Associate__c)
Product__c (Lookup of Product__c)

Requirement:
Update Inventory to sold when Product or Quantity is changed on Order Entry.

Get all Inventories which is related to Product and Status__c = 'Assigned' and Associate__c = Order.Associate__c and LIMIT = Quantity and update status to 'Sold' Order By CreatedDate LIMIT Quantity

```
trigger TriUpdateInventorySatus on Order_Entry__c (after update) {
list<Id> ProductIdList = New List <Id>();
 list<Id> AssociateIdList = New List <Id>();
Integer Quantity;
List<Id> OrderIdList  = new List<Id>();
List<Inventory__c> InventoryUpdation = new List<Inventory__c>();
for(Order_Entry__c OdEnRecord: trigger.new){
    OrderIdList.add(OdEnRecord.Order__c);
    ProductIdList.add(OdEnRecord.Product__c);
    Quantity = Integer.valueOf(OdEnRecord.Quantity__c);
}
List<Order__c> OrderRecordList = [select id,name from Order__c where id IN: OrderIdList ];
For(Order__c OrderRecord: OrderRecordList){
    AssociateIdList.add(OrderRecord.Associate__c);
}
List<Inventory__c> InventorySoqlList = [ select Id,Status__c from Inventory__c where 
                                        Product__c In: ProductIdList AND Status__c ='Assigned' 
                                        And  Associate__c IN: AssociateIdList Order By CreatedDate LIMIT: Quantity ];
for(Inventory__c InventoryRecord: InventorySoqlList){
    InventoryRecord.Status__c ='Sold';
    InventoryUpdation.add(InventoryRecord);
}
update InventoryUpdation;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare old value and new value, after that only start collecting the Ids

```
 for(Order_Entry__c OdEnRecord: trigger.new){
if(OdEnRecord.Product__c!= trigger.oldmap.get(OdEnRecord.Id).Product__c ||
       OdEnRecord.Order__c != trigger.oldmap.get(OdEnRecord.Id).Order__c){
        orderProductMap.put(OdEnRecord.Order__c,OdEnRecord.Product__c);}}
```

In below query,

```
List<Order__c> OrderRecordList = [select id,name from Order__c where id IN: OrderIdList ];
```

**You have not queried Associate__c**

Please check below code:

```
List < Inventory__c > InventoryUpdation = new List < Inventory__c > ();
Map < String, String > orderProductMap = new Map < String, String > ();
Set < String > associateOrderSet = new Set < String > ();
for (Order_Entry__c OdEnRecord: trigger.new) {
  //Product OR order changed 
  if (OdEnRecord.Product__c!= trigger.oldmap.get(OdEnRecord.Id).Product__c ||
      OdEnRecord.Order__c != trigger.oldmap.get(OdEnRecord.Id).Order__c) {
      orderProductMap.put(OdEnRecord.Order__c, OdEnRecord.Product__c);
  }
}
  List < Order__c > OrderRecordList = [select id, name, Associate__c from Order__c 
where
  id IN: orderProductMap.keyset()
];
For(Order__c OrderRecord: OrderRecordList) {
  associateOrderSet.add(OrderRecord.Associate__c);
 }
  List < Inventory__c > InventorySoqlList = [select Id, Status__c from 
Inventory__c where
  Product__c In: orderProductMap.values() AND Status__c = 'Assigned'
  And Associate__c IN: associateOrderSet 
  ];

for (Inventory__c InventoryRecord: InventorySoqlList) {
  InventoryRecord.Status__c = 'Sold';
  InventoryUpdation.add(InventoryRecord);
 }
update InventoryUpdation;
 }
```

Comment: Hi Annappa, thanks for helping .can you please suggest me somthing the problem is  code can't handle when bulk record going to update because the Quantity__c on the object Order_Entry__c is going to Inventory__c soql
List<Inventory__c> InventorySoqlList = [ select Id,Status__c from Inventory__c where 
Product__c In: ProductIdList AND Status__c ='Assigned' 
And  Associate__c IN: AssociateIdList Order ByCreatedDate   
 LIMIT: Quantity ];
As multiple record updated on Order_Entry__c object Quantity__c may have diffrent values thus for every record There should be new query...

Comment: have you checked the code. working?

Comment: Yes I have tried above code But as per the requirement Quantity__c on the object Order_Entry__c should be the limit of Inventory__c object in soql

Comment: just add that condition.

Comment: Added condition that will not work when there multiple no of record updating as each record may have diffrent Quantity__c so limit for every record will change thus soql limit may reach